# Send MySQL_RES over network

Tags: c++, mysql, serialization, mysql-connector

I'm implementing some kind of distributed database. In the nodes there are "Agent"-programs running, which get queries by a "Router" and send them to the local database. After that the results should be send back to the router.

How can I send a MYSQL_RES structure over network? What is the best way to do this? At the moment I just build a protobuf-Object with the data, but the deserialization of that object is quiet slow. And building the object needs a run over all rows.

Is there a possibility to send the mysql-binary-result to the router directly and interpret it on the router? I need the agent, as the resultsets must be examined locally, too. I'm using C/c++.

Regards

Comment: What about sending the SQL query to your remote system, and have it query MySQL directly?

Comment: I wanted to use ZMQ for network

Comment: Does anybody know, how the result-data is stored in memory in mysql_res structure?